What is location of poseBone?
I'm writing a script to change the armature of some characters, and now I'm having a hard time with the attribute 'location' of the poseBone. In my observation, it's related to the offset with bone in rest pos. But in pose mode, when I drag the pose bone along the +x axis, the location.x decreases(I'm very confused). And when I drag the pose bone along the +y axis, the location.y increases and location.z decreases!
Did I miss something about it, like orientation or other parameters? I would appreciate it if you could provide any tips!

You are moving the bone on its local axes, yes?
